# In Gatsby, how do I redirect authenticated users from the homepage / to /app without a flash of content?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, reach-router

I'm trying to implement a common user experience for web apps in which authenticated users are automatically redirected from the home page to the app.

For example, upon typing `https://example.com/` in the browser, if I'm not logged in I see the home page. But if I am logged in, I'm redirected automatically to `https://example.com/app/`

I currently have this in my `pages/index.js`:

`if (auth.user) return <Redirect noThrow from="/" to="/app" />;`

where `Redirect` is from @reach/router.

However, when I do this, the non-authenticated home page flashes briefly before the redirect kicks in. Is there a way to do this such that:

1. There is no flash of content before the redirect happens AND
2. The home page is still statically generated so that it is indexed properly by Google for SEO

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need your server to respond to the request for the homepage with a 301–303 response code and a `Location` header pointing to the desired URL (e.g. `/app/`).

Gatsby does not run any kind of server to respond to requests in production, alas, so you can't address this using Gatsby alone without some significant hacks, like hiding all of your content by default, which would result in no content being indexed by Google.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Corey, I was worried that might be the answer. This is probably an SEO question now, but I wonder if the Google crawler is "smart" enough to wait for the page to re-hydrate if I hide the content by default then unhide with a useEffect hook.

Comment: I suspect (and hope) that Google crawler may actually be able to handle this situation because my understanding is that Google crawler can run/render javascript content, for example, web apps where the page is generated by javascript.

Comment: @stevenkkim It's less about whether or not Google can index the content and more about the penalties they apply when you don't server-side render content. You also take a significant cache hit with this approach. I really don't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks Corey, I think you're right – it's not worth the risk of penalization. I appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-theme-firebase",
      options: {
        credentials: {
          apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
          authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
          databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
          projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
          storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
          messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
          appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
        },
        loginPath: "/login",
        loginRedirectPath: "/dashboard",
        socialLogins: ["google", "twitter", "facebook", "github"],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

or check https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-theme-firebase-storage/